# Can "Regula falsi" be interpreted as "False position"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, mathematics

In Mathematics, there is a technique which is known as *Regula Falsi*, and it is heavily implied that its translation to English is "False position" (for example, in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi) article). This seemed dubious, so I checked Google Translate. Indeed, the translator returns "Rule forgery". Is there a way in which "Regula falsi" can be truly translated to "False position"?

Thanks.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked to does give the rather better translation, "rule of falsehood", when quoting Humphrey Baker further down in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct (though Google Translate is not); there's no word for "position" in that phrase.

*Rēgula falsī* literally means "the rule of the false [thing]"; it's common in Latin to leave out nouns when they could be understood from context.